# dealing with sneaky spam advertisements

Tags: discussion, spam

So if you look at [this user's](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/12170/reda) current two answers, you'll see links posted back to the site in her profile (which I can safely assume is a for-profit motivation).

I find it a little lame because a large portion of fitness-experienced people probably have connections to some financial interest and are not peddling it on here via their answers.

- Can I start linking to personal trainer's websites I know that I get a kickback from?
- Can I start linking to supplement products that I'm financially vested in?

I'd much rather have a super high wall between commercial interests and the content on here. [Related q/a here](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/how-to-treat-links-in-spam).

Comment: The user (Reda) just went and did a bunch more of the same.

Comment: I did nothing Eric i have just to share my opinion as a MMA and Fitness Coach, that's all, if you have any problem there , you can tell my by message!

Comment: I'm not a moderator, it's their decision. I feel that if everyone acted like you did (posting links back to sources they are financially involved in) this place would be a mess of referral links and self serving interests.

Comment: I'm not what do you think, as i told you, i'm sharing my knowledge to help some people here, not to make money! i have some messages as thanks for my suggestion and for my solutions too, i'm here to help, not here for what do you think!

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/promotion - Maybe you should read through that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything linked back needs to be:

- Pertinent to the specific question/answer
- Make sense in the context of the linked text (in this case it seems to be random general words like "fitness" linked back to a general site)
- Summarized in the answer. The link is supplementary material.

Do please review https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/promotion